# get target element type of custom annotation

Tags: java, java-annotations

I have a custom annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD}) // NOTE: ElementType is METHOD
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

I have a generic class that takes a generic bounded type:

```
class MyWork<T extends Annotation> {
    T theAnnotation;

    public ElementType checkAnnotationElementType() {
        // how to get the target elementType of theAnnoation?
    }

}
```

What I want to achieve is to get the target element type of the `T theAnnotation`. For example the end result I want to achieve is:

```
 MyWork<MyAnnotation> foo = new MyWork();
 ElementType type = foo.checkAnnotationElementType(); // returns ElementType.METHOD
```

How can I get the element type from the generic type variable `theAnnotation` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like that. Get annotation from annotation. Make note that annotation can have more than one target type.

Note - you have to instantiate your field somehow - constructor seems like good way, generic can be ommited.

```
ElementType[] target = new MyWork<>(MyAnnotation.class).checkAnnotationElementType();
class MyWork<T extends Annotation> {

    private final Class<T> annotationClass;

    public MyWork(Class<T> annotationClass) {
        this.annotationClass = annotationClass;
    }

    public ElementType[] checkAnnotationElementType() {
        return annotationClass.getAnnotation(Target.class).value();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can we get a value of `ElementKind` from `ElementType`?

Comment: @Leem.fin considering that the enum names are different for both of them, I'd imagine you'd need to do your own mapping.